# Saving decoded polylines into a firebase database in android

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-polyline

I have already seen the code to store a single point in firebase. But what I want to know is how to store whole polylines in firebase database? A decoded polyline is basiclly List. I want to know how to store many such type of lists in firebase so that I can retrieve later and perform operations on whole polyline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase use JSON format Database

Pass types that correspond to the available JSON types as follows:

- String
- Long
- Double
- Boolean
- Map
- List

you can pass any of data type a value in setValue() method and  Lists and Map ,too.

Example:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
String[] names = {"John","Tim","Sam","Ben"};
List nameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
// Now set value with new nameList
ref.setValue(nameList);
```

you can pass your custome object list,too.

Comment: can you please share some example code if you have.

Comment: yes , you can check now this is how to pass List in Firebase, if you find it useful mark it as true, thanks..

Comment: and can you please show me how can i retrieve back this list object after saving it in firebase database.